# Did the manga explain why Muzan had a family?

Tags: demon-slayer

As a demon, did the manga clarify why (and how) Muzan had a wife and child? The anime didn't seem to explore or discuss this interesting detail.

Comment: Most likely as a disguise. No one would suspect him, which was proven by the fact that no Hashira (or at least the current Hashira in the manga) has ever found or met him before Tanjiro. Only Tanjiro was able to find and encounter Muzan (and only because he recognized his scent).

Comment: @W.Are  Must have had pretty good control to not eat them. That might bring up a question for another time - can demons father children? Or was his daughter adopted or his wife's child (not his biologically)?

Comment: IIRC, these details were not thoroughly explained in the manga so I can't provide a good enough answer. If I would guess, they wouldn't be biologically related. In the manga, they were not the only human family he had. At the later part of the series, he pretended to be a child under some rich family. I assume he disguised himself as different persons throughout the years. Then again, this is just me guessing.

Comment: To be able to blend in human society, he plays many roles in society at different time period, even becoming a child or having a family of his own. This help him disguising himself from his demon form as well as reach out to places quickly.